# Вредно ли использование ob_start

Tags: php, yii

Для удобной передачи одному из виджетов JS и html кода (визуально переделывать JS удобнее), стал использовать ob_start (и ob_get_clean). Но получается что на одной страничке, понатыкано 3-4 блока вида:

```
<?ob_start();?>
alert('Быдлокодить - плохо');
<?$alert = ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

Пример конечно сильно упрощенный, но суть передал. Вопрос: правильно ли это? И если нет, то почему.

Comment: Технических проблем вроде нет, насколько плохо использование глобального состояния - довольно плохо, но это PHP, nuff said

Answer (score 1):

Почему нет? Если другого выхода нет.

Answer (score 1):

php == логика системы

html+js+css == представление (Пользовательский интерфейс)

Это разные вещи и их крайне нежелательно смешивать. Когда суммарный объем вашего кода перевалит за XXXXX строк, вы сами будете не рады.

[Почитайте на досуге](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller).

Comment: Про модель MVC я естественно знаю, и даже пытаюсь практиковать правила "толстой модели, тонкого контроллера", но кажется всему буду учиться на собственных ошибках =/

Answer (score 1):

Любой инструмент может применяться в разных целях и с разными результатами. Посмотрите на свой код - что он напоминает? Если он понятен и красив - значит, `ob_start` был применен по назначению. Если же код в итоге напоминает нечитаемое месиво - значит, `ob_start` был лишним.

Разумеется, довольно трудно оценить красоту кода, если не видно альтернатив. Расскажу про мой любимый подход.

Любой код можно разделить на две части: неизменяемую логику и параметры. В вашем случае весь код - неизменяем, потому сделаю небольшое усложнение:

```
<? $message = 'Быдлокодить - плохо' ?>
<? ob_start(); ?>
alert('<?=message?>');
<? $alert = ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

Теперь у нас есть две части кода - неизменяемая логика (вызов `alert`) - и вычисляемый параметр (строка "Быдлокодить - плохо").

Неизменяемая часть выносится в отдельный файл и оформляется в виде функции.  Параметры выносятся в объект настроек:

```
function widget_show_alert(cfg) {
    alert(cfg.message);
}
```

Потом этот файл будет добавлен на страницу и тем самым функция станет для нас доступна - а нам осталось эту функцию в нужном месте вызвать, передав ей параметр. Формировать объект настроек "по-старинке" на PHP неудобно - да и это поломает всю красоту подхода. Поэтому я воспользуюсь тем фактом, что любой JSON является валидным литералом JS:

```
$cfg = json_encode(array('message' => 'Быдлокодить - плохо'))
$alert = "widget_show_alert($cfg)";
```

Заодно исчезла потенциальная уязвимость вида "js-инъекция".

Лично мне кажется, что код стал красивее. Вам может показаться иначе :)